# adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory is breaking the UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, uikit, swift5

I'm having a button which is being configured with extension that looks like this:

```
extension UIButton {
   func applyStyle(_ type: CustomButtonType) {
        titleLabel?.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
        switch type {
        case .primary:
            backgroundColor = K.Colors.callToActionPrimary
            layer.cornerRadius = 10
            setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        
        case .secondary:
            backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackground
            layer.cornerRadius = 10
            layer.borderColor = K.Colors.callToActionPrimaryBorder?.cgColor
            layer.borderWidth = 1
            setTitleColor(K.Colors.callToActionPrimary, for: .normal)
        
        case .tertiary:
            backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackground
            layer.cornerRadius = 10
            setTitleColor(K.Colors.callToActionPrimary, for: .normal)            
        }
    }
}
```

The order of button setup looks like this:

```
button1.applyStyle(.primary)
button1.setTitle("Some title", for: .normal)
```

[image]

While this works fine for the normal flow, once I add a UI test the setTitleColor() seems to have broken (or executed at later point).

However if I comment out the line `titleLabel?.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true` it works in the UI testing.
Why is it breaking?

Comment: Show the code of the button itself. How do you set the title? It seems the issue is with the order of calling functions.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini I updated the question with an edit, I included the call order pls check

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this happens, but I found a workaround.
I extracted the problematic line of code into separate function like this:

```
func allowAdjustFont() {
    titleLabel?.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
}
```

And then in the code I'm calling them in sequence like this:

```
actionButton.applyStyle(.primary)
actionButton.allowAdjustFont()
```

This seems to work both for normal app lifecycle and screenshot tests.